# How can I compile a C program file which I created using the Libre Office editor?

Tags: compiling, text-editor, c

I'm new to Linux and I need some help!

I am trying to compile the code taken from [**this post**](http://groups.google.com/group/linux.kernel/msg/36c53d79832fc3f5) to the `linux-kernel` mailing list.

I have pasted the file into Libre Office and saved it as `pairing_tool.c` (**Not** as `pairing_tool.c.odt`. I have renamed the file to `pairing_tool.c`.)

But when I use this command line: `gcc -o pairing_tool pairing_tool.c` in the terminal, I get many errors.

- What did I do wrong?
- Should I paste the text into a special text editor?

Also just to be clear, I've used the text included only in between

`#include <linux/input.h>`

and

`return 0;

}`

So I haven't put the comments. I think it is good this way, is it?

Comment: If you are at all curious as to why using Libre Office did *not* work, then all you have to do is (1) create the file again by pasting into Libre Office and then saving it as (for example) `trythis.c`. (2) Open `trythis.c` with the `gedit` text edit. I think you will immediately understand why you had so many compile errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should use a text editor, for example `gedit` which is installed in Ubuntu by default. LibreOffice Writer is a text processor and it saves its files with some additional markup which C compiler does not understand.

To run `gedit`, press the Super (Win logo) key and type "gedit".

Apart from saving the program in plain text format, you will also need to install the C compiler and stuff, which you can do with

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

(although I think you already managed to install it)

Btw, I can confirm that the program compiles nicely and even runs after that :)

Comment: oki ;) solved!!

Answer (score 0):

C source code fila is a  ASCII text file with c extension. In Libre office I have saved fila as txt. Editor adds txt extension so 
I have changed it to c, then I can compile file with no errors using gcc

Answer (score 0):

You've discovered the basic computing concept that the file name and extension actually has *no bearing whatsoever* on the file contents, or the type of information encoded in the file. You can rename cats.png as cats.doc all you want, but that does NOT make it a Word document containing an informational report on feline companions. It will still be an image file in the PNG format, it's just named incorrectly to look like a Word document. Your OS will probably be confused if you double-click on it, but the contents of the file are unchanged and the word processor app that launches when you double-click will probably give you an error dialog.

You did exactly the same thing. You took a Libre Office document file, which is basically a Word document (actually Word can open it as well, these days) with all the formatting information, table of contents, and whatever else may be included, and then renamed it to ".c", leaving all that information intact. The compiler expects plain textual data, with none of that other information.

File extensions are a useful *convention* to give the user hints as to what might be inside, and also to give the OS hints as to which program to use to view the file content. But they mean nothing more. That's why you needed to actually create a plain-text document, using a plain-text editor, rather than use a Word Processor and rename the file to lie to your OS.